# Extending Optimum WiFi range

Tags: wireless-bridge, repeater

How would one go about extending an optimum wifi connection? I would assume a bridge would be better than a repeater so the network wouldn't suffer from reduced bandwidth, however I have learned I would need to know the MAC address of their router which I do not have access to... what would you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Pull a network cable to the new location and install another AP there. If that's not an option, then use 5GHz backhaul between the APs and 2.4GHz to your wireless clients (or vice versa).

Answer (score -2):

I recently found an android app "Network info" which allows one to find all the necessary info like IP and MAC addresses to set up a bridged network, even without having direct access to the router.
There are also more complicated ways of doing this (using the Linux framework of android for example, or command prompt on Windows)...let google be your guide :  )